# Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-3"

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory

I want to deploy 5 war in APACHE TOMCAT 7.0.45

2 war containts Web DYNAMIC PROJECT (JSF, Hibernate, Spring IOC, Primefaces)
2 war containts Web Service (SOAP)
1 war containt a Simple Servlet to download same files from server

current deployment I have no error. but, whene I want to access in the apps, I get this errors :

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread “http-apr-8080-exec-3”
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

i don't use Maven.

Comment: Which java version do you run? If it's Java 7, what size has your PermGen in Tomcat? Maybe it's just to small.

Comment: whene i find PermGen  of TOMCAT ? i use java 7

Comment: I resolve problem with this tutorial : http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/